# mysql_query error when i try to get interval between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to use `'mulai'` as variable that can be used to get the interval.

My query is like this :

```
SELECT sdm_id,
       LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(tgl_mulai, INTERVAL 0 MONTH))AS mulai,
       DATEDIFF(mulai,tgl_mulai) AS total
FROM pengajuan_cuti;
```

and I got this error:

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'mulai' in 'field list'`

Comment: Are you trying to pass off `as mulai` into and be used by `DATEDIFF(mulai,tgl_mulai)`? When using `as something` it's usually used as a row alias. I.e.: `$row['mulai'];`

Comment: ya i tried like that, is there another way?

Comment: I don't know for 100% certainty, but I kind of doubt it, to tell you the truth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias as the function parameter, and add `INTERVAL 0 MONTH` to a date did nothing.

Try:

```
SELECT sdm_id, 
       LAST_DAY(tgl_mulai) AS mulai,
       DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY(tgl_mulai), tgl_mulai) AS total
FROM pengajuan_cuti
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not performing any `group` operations, then you can use session variables to achieve as you desired.

**Example**:

```
SELECT sdm_id,
       @mulai := LAST_DAY( DATE_ADD( tgl_mulai, INTERVAL 0 MONTH ) ) AS mulai,
       DATEDIFF( @mulai, tgl_mulai ) AS total
FROM pengajuan_cuti;
```